# The timer is terminated when the view changes

Tags: swift, swift3, view, timer

I am not a native English speaker and I am writing with a translator. 
I want you to understand if the context is strange.

My Question is, 
When the button is pressed, the timer operates, but when the view is switched, the timer is not operating.

**I wonder how the timer can be maintained even if the view changes.**

```
var time : Int = 0
var onehour : Int = 60
var timer = Timer()
@IBAction func pressSuncream(_ sender: Any) { // Suncream 버튼
    useSuncream.setImage(UIImage(named: "test"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "hello"
        content.body = "timer"
        content.badge = 1

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3600, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerdone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(QuestView.updatetime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

func updatetime() {
    time += 1
    if time == 60 {
        time = 0
        onehour -= 1
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.suncreamTime.text = String(self.onehour)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do with the view ? Is it released or remains in the stack ?

Comment: I am using the navigation controller view and when I press Button in main view, it goes to timerView. In timerView, press button to activate timer and press back button to move to mainview

I used show segue when switching from mainview to timerView.
Please understand that I am a beginner and I can not fully understand your question.

Comment: Well, that does answer it. So, you have a view, which has timer in it. And when you press a button to it, you go back to previous view controller, and the view gets deallocated, it gets released and so are all the objects that are within the class, and so your timer does not work then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you switch to the mainView,you can store the value of `onehour` in the `UserDefaults` at the `override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) { }`.
when you into the timerView,you can get the value at the `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {}`

eg:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefault.set(onehour, forKey: "onehour")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let onehour = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "onehour") {
        self.onehour = onehour as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not him being able to access the Int "60", it's keeping the timer assigned to a value in multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could do this, is to make the timer variable global. This is probably a "dirty" way to do it, and if there really are terrible ramifications of doing this, someone let me know and I'll take this down.

Essentially all you would need to do is define it outside of any class like so:

```
var timer: NSTimer?
class MyClass: UIViewController {
    ...
}
```

This way you can access it from any file. I would say that you are generally discouraged from doing this unless you have to, so it's more of a last-resort option.